# maximization as a categorical construction (e.g. limit)?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have a set $S$, and a lattice $L$, and a function $f:S\to L$. We can define the constructs $\max_sf(s)$ and $\arg\max_sf(s)$.

Is there a way to characterize $\max$ and $\arg\max$ categorically, based on the objects $S,L$, and morphism $f$?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathrm{max}$ or $\mathrm{sup}$? In general $\mathrm{max}_s f(s)$ might not be defined, e.g. for the function $f : \{ 0,1 \} \to \mathcal{P}(\{0,1\})$ given by $f(0) = \{ 0 \}$ and $f(1) = \{ 1 \}$. If you *do* mean $\mathrm{sup}$, then $\mathrm{sup}_s f(s)$ is the colimit of $f$ regarded as a functor from a discrete category to a poset category; or equivalently it's the coproduct of the objects (elements) $f(s) \in L$. Not sure about $\mathrm{arg~max}$.

Comment: argmax might also not be defined, e.g. the maximizer might fail to exist, or it might fail to be unique and then you need a way to pick from the different options. Mathematically it's very poorly behaved.